# Command binding is not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a user control where one text box and button is there

```
<UserControl x:Class="Search.View.SearchView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Search.ViewModel" x:Name="SearchUserControl"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="250" DataContext="{DynamicResource SearchViewModel}">       
<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModel:SearchViewModel x:Key="SearchViewModel"></viewModel:SearchViewModel>
</UserControl.Resources>   
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <TextBox x:Name="TxtSearch"  Height="20" Width="100"></TextBox>
            <Button x:Name="BtnSearchButton" Content="Search" Height="20" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"   Width="Auto" Margin="5,0,5,0" ></Button>
        </StackPanel>       
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

in in my ViewModel file :

```
   public RelayCommand SearchCommand { get; set; }

   public  SearchViewModel() 
    {
         SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(TestSearch);
    }

    public void TestSearch(object p)
    {

    }
```

when i am using this user control on any view . Command binding is not working any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Is the DataContext applied correctly?

Comment: When debugging, check your `Output Window` in Visual Studio. Are there any binding errors there?

Comment: My usercontrol xaml is above please see if there any issue

Comment: I have tested your code and it works fine, what exactly is wrong ?

Comment: <UserControl x:Class="Search.View.SearchView" is a usercontrol so it is reusable .when i use it in another xaml as a user control then button click command is not working.

Comment: if i am binding Search text box with text binding then it's  working .but button command binding is not working.